# How to fusion an AND et OR filter/condition in Magento?

Tags: magento2.3, filter, order-collection, addfield, condition

how to fusion this instructions:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('updated_at', ['from' => $from])
           ->addFieldToFilter('updated_at', ['to' => $to])
or
$collection->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['from' => $from])
           ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['to' => $to]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$collection->addFieldToFilter(
    ['created_at', 'updated_at'], // the field names
    [ // the conditions
        [ // the conditions for 'created_at' (first field)
            ['from' => $from],
            ['to' => $to]
        ],
        [ // the conditions for 'updated_at' (second field)
            ['from' => $from],
            ['to' => $to]
        ],
    ]
);
```