# How to add AND OR AND conditions in a product collection?

Tags: collection, filter, customer-attribute, addfield, condition

**ORIGINAL POST** Comment ajouter des conditions ET OU ET dans une collection de produits?

comment pourrais filtrer une collection de produit par:
(attribut A : condition A **And** attribut A : condition B) **OR** (attribut B : condition C **And** attribut B : condition D)

---

**TRANSLATION** how can I filter a product collection by  (attribut A : condition A And attribut A : condition B) OR (attribut B : condition C And attribut B : condition D)

Answer (score 0):

**FR**: Tu peux essayer le code ci dessous (c'est la meme solution que j'ai donne a ton premier post [How to fusion an AND et OR filter/condition in Magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/332380/how-to-fusion-an-and-et-or-filter-condition-in-magento) sur le meme sujet):

**EN:** you can try the code below (it's the same solution that I gave for your first post [How to fusion an AND et OR filter/condition in Magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/332380/how-to-fusion-an-and-et-or-filter-condition-in-magento) on the same topic)

```php
$collection->addFieldToFilter(
    ['created_at', 'updated_at'], // the field names
    [ // the conditions
        [ // the conditions for 'created_at' (first field)
            ['from' => $from],
            ['to' => $to]
        ],
        [ // the conditions for 'updated_at' (second field)
            ['from' => $from],
            ['to' => $to]
        ],
    ]
);
```